# Restart a TCP Server

Tags: java, android, networking, tcp

I have a TCP server in my android application. The server starts running immediately. With one button click, i want to stop the server and with another one, restart the server again.

My server is like this:

```
serverSocket = new ServerSocket(1292);
while (true) {
 Socket client = serverSocket.accept();            
 ServersClient s = new ServersClient(client);
 Thread clientThread = new Thread(s);
 clientThread.run();
}
```

I successfully handle closing with this code:

```
serverSocket.close();
```

After this code, no clients can connect.

What should i do to restart it now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ServerSocket` listens for new connections.

`Socket` is the connection instance that `serverSocket.accept()` returns.

You want to close the `Socket` instance to close connection with a particular client.
Closing `ServerSocket` will unbind the application from the port.

Comment: Oh yes thank you very much. I closed the socket instead of ServerSocked and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

A ServerSocket can not be opened again after it has been closed. Therefore you just execute your first code snippet again, starting with the creation of a new ServerSocket instance.